# Proof of Pythagoras' Theorem

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

If you want to proof Pythagoras' theorem, and part of the proof uses a right-angled triangle and trignonometric ratios $\sin, \cos$ (but not the identity $\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta = 1$) and you complete the proof by showing that $\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta = 1$, would that be considered a proof that contains a circular argument?

Comment: Write down the actual argument. It is hard to tell from that. Ah! and clarify the 'from where'. The argument is a proof of Pythagoras being implied form what assumptions.

Comment: It's a conceptual question.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire as mentioned, the proof does *not* make use of that identity. But instead proves it (not by using Pythagoras' Theorem).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No, it wouldn't. A proof is not a proof in isolation. Proofs have assumptions. You can have a proof of Pythagoras starting from the vector space axioms, you can have one starting from Euclid's, you can have one starting from that equation. They are just different. Even a circular proof can be a proof, only a very weak one. Also, if a set of axioms implies a theorem, then in a way, the theorem was implicitly assumed by assuming the axioms.

Comment: Again, it depends on the specific proof.  My guess is that the proof uses *another* identity that assumes Pythagoras' Theorem, and you just proved that you could generate the one identify from the other.

Additionally, I assume that you added a final step where you multiplied by $C^2$, because that would in fact give you the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: The circularity that is unwanted, is when you have some axioms, and your argument makes use of an extra assumption that is not part of the ones that you wanted and either the axioms don't imply that extra assumption or the argument doesn't show how it is derived from the axioms. So, to be able to give a judgment, not only you need to show the actual argument, but specify what are the assumptions that you will allow.

Comment: I'm assuming the context here is that the regular proof of the Pythagorean theorem involving is unintuitive, but the ideas of sine and cosine are somewhat more natural. Or maybe you're just curious, IDK. In any case though - if one wanted to go really out of the way - one could prove the sine squared plus cosine squared identity as equaling 1 using the Taylor expansion of sine and cosine, since I believe you technically do not need to know the Pythagorean theorem to take the derivative of them.

Comment: Also, and this likely isn't what you had in mind, but you can simply prove that sin squared plus cos squared equals one by labeling a triangle with sides of sin, cos, and a hypotenuse of 1 and then proceed to use any other proof of the theorem.

Comment: Oh and I think (?) you could prove it by writing sin and cos as their functions involving complex exponents and just verify it, which would be the same thing as the Taylor expansion except simpler and maybe a little less satisfying.

Comment: My initial thoughts for a simpler mostly algebraic approach would be to find something that has two proofs, one requiring sin^2+cos^2=1 and one without it, then go from one proof to the other by setting the results equal to each other.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn  At school we were first introduced to the definitions of trigonometric ratios, and the using the Pythagoras theorem, it was shown that they are related by the identity $\sin^2 + \cos^2=1$ amongst others. So can it be said that if you use the ratios but not the identity (in this or any other form), then you are not using the Pythagoras theorem?

Comment: I think you're asking it there's a way to prove that sin^2+cos^2=1 without detouring through Pythagoras, or if you do proving an equivalent of it - but fundamentally, proving sin^2+cos^2=1 based just off of the definitions of sine and cosine as ratios (is that right?). If that's the case, depending on how you frame the question, maybe (???) you can't because the ratios are not just of any two numbers, *but two numbers in a right triangle* which is a more restrictive condition.